# Same height on resizable boxes when truncated

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is is possible to have 4 columns in a row, each column has different amount of text but each has a 'read more' link at the end. On a mac in a firefox browser I can change the length of text so each column is the same height however when preview on a pc in another browser the padding/font size is slightly different which makes the boxes different heights. Also if you are to zoom in on the browser window this changes the height as well.

I can't put a fixed height because when you click on the 'read more' link it opens and adjusts the size so it grows with the text.

This is the image example: 
 http://forewardsapp.com/images/resize.png

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle, so we can see the code.

Comment: When I put it in js Fiddle I am having issues with the read more working..

http://jsfiddle.net/NMSQn/

Comment: You need to configure JSFiddle to load the jQuery library. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/NMSQn/1/

Answer (score 4):

I achieved this on one of my sites using this in the styles:

```
margin: 0px 0px -100%;
padding: 0px 0px 100%;
```

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMH53/3/)

Comment: This will only work, when you have defined a fixed height, also you override your first margin later in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I updated the fiddle, it works with fluid heights too, I have the height set to 20% in the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use flexbox

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NMSQn/3/

```
.column-center
{
    display: flex;
}

.column-center .emotions
{
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```